# Xamarin.Forms Android app is failing build with System.Security.Cryptography.Cng error

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have suddenly hit a wall with testing my Xamarin.Forms app.  IT has suddenly started throwing the two messages below and failing (on my Android Emulator) immediately after the splash screen disappears.

I get the following warning during the build:

```
Ignoring C:\Users\geral\.nuget\packages\system.security.cryptography.cng\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.6\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll as it is a Reference Assembly
```

And then the Output windows shows these message when the app fails:

```
11-18 09:33:29.257 D/Mono    (31723): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks[0xe1503180] -> Mono.Android[0xe15031e0]: 26
11-18 09:33:29.260 D/Mono    (31723): Assembly Loader probing location: 'System.Security.Cryptography.Cng'.
11-18 09:33:29.260 F/monodroid-assembly(31723): Could not load assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Cng' during startup registration.
11-18 09:33:29.260 F/monodroid-assembly(31723): This might be due to an invalid debug installation.
11-18 09:33:29.260 F/monodroid-assembly(31723): A common cause is to 'adb install' the app directly instead of doing from the IDE.
```

In searching the web, I found a few articles that seemed related but nothing fixes the error.  I have updated all NuGet packages and the Android SDK to the latest available. I am out of ideas.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63584/android-could-not-load-assembly-xxx-during-startup-registration

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42405/debug-deployment-to-device-works-fine-release-fails-with-odd-messages-anybody-have-a-fix-for-this

Anyone have additional suggestions?

Comment: Please try:
After running on debug, and going back to release mode the devil came with it.
My solution was removing the "data" folder of the application on the internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer was a little obvious after I had some time to come back to it.  I added the NuGet package directly to my projects and now things are working correctly again.  I had assumed the Reference would be sufficient, but in this case a direct reference was apparently needed.  Still not sure why, or what changed that made it suddenly become a problem.

But if you get these message in the future try adding the package directly.